# C# : Verify if DateTime is in Ascending Order

Tags: c#

I have code below for getting `starttime` for each event. How can I verify if that time is now in ascending order?

```
List<dynamic> list= new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var item in jsonData.x[0].y)
{
    list.Add(item.StartTime.Value);            
    Console.WriteLine(item.AdvertisedStartTime);            
}
```

Now I want to verify if the `List` is in ascending order based on time.

`UTC Time = 2017-01-09T02:05:00Z`

with  below

```
var list1 = list.OrderBy(x => x.TimeOfDay).ToList();
```

it will order the list by `TimeofDay` but I actually want to verify if `list` is in ascending order.

How should i approach for this ?

Comment: Use a for loop. Check if the previous time was greater than the current time. If it is, it's not sorted.

Comment: @Rob can you able to help with sample code ?

Comment: Hi @v.api! I piggy-backed off of the comment from @Rob and added some sample code for you below. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer

You can use a `foreach` loop to ensure that the value of each proceeding `DateTime` instance in the `List` is greater-than-or-equal-to the value of the previous `DateTime` instance in the `List`.

#### ForEach Loop Explanation

The `foreach` loop walks through each instance in the `List` in order, starting with the first item in the `List` and finishing at the last item in the `List`.

Here is Microsoft's official documentation on `foreach` loops:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

#### CompareTo Explaination

Inside of the `foreach` loop, we are utilizing the `CompareTo` method to compare the `DateTime` instances. In C#, the `CompareTo` method can be used to compare two instances of the same type.

If the first instance precedes the instance inside of `CompareTo`, it returns `-1`. If the first instance has the same position (or in this case the same `DateTime` value) of the instance inside of `CompareTo`, it returns `0`. Finally, if the first instance follows the instance inside of `CompareTo`, it returns `1`.

Here is Microsoft's official documentation on `CompareTo`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ah99705

#### Sample Code

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

bool IsDateTimeListInAscendingOrder(List<DateTime> dateTimeList)
{
    var previousDateTimeItem = dateTimeList.FirstOrDefault();

    foreach (DateTime currentDateTimeItem in dateTimeList)
    {
        if (currentDateTimeItem.CompareTo(previousDateTimeItem) < 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation !

Answer (score 0):

list.OrderBy() use asc order, list.OrderByDescending() use desc order. If you want to verify, you can use DateTime method CompareTo(), code snippet as followings.

```
 DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime dt2=DateTime.Now+TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
 var value = dt2.CompareTo(dt1);
 value may be -1,0,1, means earlier, same, later
```